# How to move ALL windows from external display to the main laptop display?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, windows

Is there a simple keyboard shortcut, or setting to enable a shortcut, or anything, that. would allow me to quickly move ALL open windows from the external display to the main laptop display?

The problem is that frequently, I need to plug the laptop for a presentation or a class and I have a bunch of windows on the external display that shouldn't be there. So I'd prefer it doesn't remember which windows were in the external display from work, and just assume I want all windows to start in the main display only!

Comment: System Prefs > Mission Control - what's the status of 'Displays have separate Spaces'?

Comment: Alternatively, you could hide all apps except that one you use for the presentation (under [App name] > Hide Others).

Comment: @Tetsujin "Displays have separate Spaces" is on. Should I turn it off?

Comment: @jaume If I understand correctly, that does not move windows from one screen to another, right? If I unhide the app, it go back to the external display.

Comment: Yes, that's right, windows would go back to is previous location (either on the external or built-in display) when unhiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in command to move windows from Space to Space.

As you use 'Displays have separate Spaces', then set up one additional space & leave it empty.

If you didn't have it switched on, any windows on the 2nd screen would all drop back to the primary each time you unplug the secondary [and would not automatically return when you re-connect].

Comment: Thanks, this does what I want. Why 'Displays have separate Spaces' is on by default? It seems to me a more "sane" setting is to have this off!

Comment: A lot of people seem to like it. idk why:\ I switched it off the day it first appeared, maybe a decade ago. I like my displays to shift in pairs. It does mean you can't use fullscreen though [which I also see zero use for on two 27" displays] I'd guess it's more useful to people with laptops & disparate display sizes.

Comment: What's the default setting for this option? Off? In any case thanks for pointing it out. I think I also find it more natural to have this off.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember what the default was, it's been too long.